# set @Html.DropDownList selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Basically my action return a viewModel with a List - each language has anID and a title

So in my view I have the following fropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("Languages", new SelectList(Model.lstLanguages, "LanguageID", "Name"), "SELCT  LANGUAGE----->",new { id = "ddlLanguages" })
```

SOmy question is - as I will have other views with dropdown and I will save in a session the id of the chosen language so when the user is redirected back by to this view

I want to be able to say  something like this

```
ddllanguages.SelectedItem = @HttpContext.Current.Session["langID"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "Languages", 
    new SelectList(
        Model.lstLanguages, 
        "LanguageID", 
        "Name",
        Session["langID"]
    ), 
    "<-----SELECT  LANGUAGE----->",
    new { id = "ddlLanguages" }
)
```

Comment: Благодаря - а знеш ли дали мога да направя проверка - ако сесията не е нула - да е стойността на сесията, ако Session is null -  тогава да сложа примерно две

Comment: @MilkaSalkova, StackOverflow is an English only website, so please adhere to this rule. Let me translate your question for others: *is it possible to check whether the session contains a value and if it doesn't put 2 for example*. The answer is, yes, you can do that pretty easily. Just use the null coalescing operator: `Session["langID"] ?? "2"`.

Comment: Thankkks Darin and please forgive me for my mistake :)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I have similar issue and I'm using dropdownlistfor here and also I want to assign the session value to the dropdownlistfor,I followed your answer but everytime entire list of element is getting binded to the dropdown with first element as Select .Here I want the session value to be shown in the dropdown.Please help.